# How would an alarm button work in a bathroom scale?

Tags: pcb

I am given a bathroom scale that I have to reverse engineer and beneath the bathroom scale, there is a button that sets an alarm for 24 hours from when you pressed it so that it can remind you the next day at that same time to check your weight. On the circuit board, there is the button that sets off the alarm and there is a soundbox where the alarm noise comes from. How are the seconds measured? Is it in cycles, what units would they be in? How does the scale know when 24 hours is up and how does it display that information onto the LCD screen? And when the alarm, rings, it can be turned off as soon as you step on the scale and if not the alarm will sound for 20 seconds; how does this function work?

All I know is that when you press the button, the LCD icon displays an alarm icon which indicates the alarm has been programmed to sound at the exact time every 24 hours.[image]

Comment: you already said that the alarm is in cycles and from what you said, it is measured in 24 hour units .... why would the scale need to measure seconds? ... does it have a timer display? ... all you need is counter that takes 24 hours to count to some number

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I am always wondering why someone should reverse engineer something except, if it's for personal knowledge, or the PCB is too old to get spare parts. Is this the case? Or can you tell why you want to get to know this PCB?

Comment: @Eggi probably the first one. And good on them for it!

Answer (score 13):

The metal cylindrical component is the lower left is a crystal. The crystal oscillations are used to create an accurate timebase.

The black epoxy blob in the center covers the fragile bond wires of an integrated circuit (IC). The IC is probably a microcontroller. Most microcontrollers have internal timers to create delays, but the delays are relatively short. To get long delays, software takes over.

Reverse engineering an IC is extraordinarily difficult. With a lot of money and motivation it can be done, but you need specialized equipment and very experienced people.

Answer (score 6):

"How are the seconds measured?" - The exact details of this would be difficult to determine without further information about the design.  In generic terms, many microcontrollers (my guess that would be U1 in this case) have internal timers that can be programmed.  These are either driven by an internal oscillator or an external clock source.  See the component just south of C6 and C7.  That is a crystal that oscillates at a very specific frequency.  This could be the known time base.  The specifics of this product would be known to the designer but could potentially be determined with some poking around.

"Is it in cycles, what units would they be in?" - This again depends on the design, but with a known clock source as described above, they would be in ticks.  Each tick would be the length of the clock source period, potentially divided by some prescaler.  If the clock oscillates at fc = 32.768 kHz, the period would be 1/fc ~= 30.5 us.

The button is probably an input to the microcontroller, so it knows when the button is pressed.  Therefore, can clear/start timers when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The little metal cylinder is almost certainly a timing crystal. Most likely with a frequency of 32768Hz. At least the people I worked with referred to these small low frequency crystals as "watch crystals".

Inside the microcontroller there will be a crystal driver that drives said crystal and produces a clock signal. This signal can be divided down and fed to timers inside the microcontroller.

Many microcontrollers only have generic timers, designed to track relatively short periods, it is possible to track long periods of time based on these, but it requires waking up the main CPU frequently to count the number of timer periods that have elapsed.

However some microcontrollers have a specific "real time clock" peripheral that can measure long periods of time* in hardware and can set an "alarm" to wake up the main CPU core later. For example the PIC18F45J11 has a real time clock, intended to represent dates in the range 2000 to 2099 and can generate either a single one-shot alarm or a repeating alarm that repeats every half-second, every second, every ten seconds, every minute, every 10 minutes, every hour, every day, every week, every month or every year.

Unfortunately I don't think you are going to get very far with reverse engineering your bathroom scale. You can figure out what the items connected to the microcontroller do, but figuring out what is going on inside the microcontroller is going to be an uphill struggle, you would likely have to.

1. Remove the epoxy blob, I believe this is possible chemically but the chemicals involved are fairly nasty.
2. Try and figure out what the micro-controller is, at best this is likely to require a powerful microscope, and even when you do get an image it may or may not have any useful identifying markings.
3. Try and figure out how to get the code out of the microcontroller, while many microcontrollers support readback of the code they often have "code protect" options to disable this, there can be possible bypasses though glitching the clock, but the exact details will depend heavily on the particular microcontroller.